# Using javascript, how do I get the background color of a table cell when I click on it?

Tags: javascript, html, background-color

I want to have an alert pop up that shows me the background of a table cell whenever i click on it.  I just can't seem to find or figure out how to grab the background color.

My table cell looks like this:

```
<td id="s0" onclick="selectCell(event)">0</td>
```

My selectCell function looks like this:

```
function selectCell(e){
  alert(e.target.backgroundColor);  //this gives me 'undefined'
  alert(e.target.bgcolor);          //this gives me 'undefined'
  alert(e.target.bgColor);          //nothing shows up. i don't believe this is a valid property
  //once i know i am properly grabbing the color i will do stuff with it here.
}
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
#s0 {
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The styles of a node are in the styles property, for example:

```
e.target.style.backgroundColor;
```

However this works only for those styles declared with the in-line `style` attribute. If CSS is assigned (as it should be) using a stylesheet, you'll need to use:

```
window.getComputedStyle(e.target, null).backgroundColor;
```

Internet Explorer, unfortunately, doesn't implement the `getComputedStyle()` option, instead offering `currentStyle` (mind, they don't support `e.target` either, I think, at least in versions prior to 8?). I don't have Internet Explorer with which to test, but the docs *suggest* that it should be used:

```
var e = window.event ? window.event : e,
    elementNode = e.target !== null ? e.target : e.srcElement;
elementNode.currentStyle.backgroundColor;
```

References:

- [`currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- [`Element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.style).
- [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle).

Comment: your second one is awesome

Answer (score -1):

You can do it easily by Jquery css() function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).click(function () {
          var color = $(this).css("background-color");
          alert(color);
     });
 });
```

For more detail have a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/css/) example