# Javascript - Assigning a new ID to an element

Tags: javascript, css, properties

I'm very new to Javascript and am struggling with how it all actually works. I can't seem to find an answer to this question.

I've created a table and given each table cell a unique ID. I've also given each cell it's own background colour with css. Using Javascript, how can I find out what the background colour is for each cell? How do I actually access that property of each cell?

Thanks
Dave

Comment: It depends on *how* you assigned the colors. Why don't you post some of your HTML so that people can provide an accurate answer?

Comment: Hi it seems like what you are trying here is the solution ..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116909/using-javascript-how-do-i-get-the-background-color-of-a-table-cell-when-i-click

Comment: FWIW, giving each cell a unique ID is probably not an ideal design choice, although naturally it depends on what you're doing.

Comment: I'm trying to make a simple colour picker. There's only 8 colours to choose from so I made a table with one row and 8 cells. I gave each cell a background colour in css but I just haven't been able to work out how to get javascript to know what that colour is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this:

1. Getting the element
2. Getting the color assigned to it

#### Getting the element

If you know the cell ID, you can use `document.getElementById`:

```
var element = document.getElementById("the-id");
```

If you want to do this in response to an event that happens on the cell, for instance a `click`, you can use an event handler. For instance, suppose the table has the `id` `"my-table"`:

```
document.getElementById("my-table").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var element = event.target;
    while (element && element.tagName !== "TD") {
        if (element === this) {
            // No cell was clicked
            return;
        }
        element = element.parentNode;
    }

    // ...use element here
});
```

That hooks the `click` event on the table (so you don't have to hook it on every single cell), then when the click reaches the table, finds the `td` that the click passed through on its way to the table (if any).

Note: Old versions IE (IE8 and earlier) don't have `addEventListener`, they have Microsoft's predecessor to it, `attachEvent`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) shows how to work around that if you need to.

#### Getting the color

If you assigned the color directly on the element, via the `style` attribute (`<td style="color: ..."...`), you can use the `style` object on the element:

```
var color = element.style.color;
```

If it's assigned via a stylesheet, that won't work, you need to use `getComputedStyle` instead:

```
var color = getComputedStyle(element).color;
```

Again, old versions of IE are a pain in this regard, they don't have `getComputedStyle` but they do have a `currentStyle` property on elements, so you can polyfill (shim) `getComputedStyle`:

```
if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
    window.getComputedStyle = function(element, pseudo) {
        if (typeof pseudo !== "undefined") {
            throw "The second argument of getComputedStyle can't be polyfilled";
        }
        return element.currentStyle;
    };
}
```

#### Example

Here's an example (modern browsers only) where you click a cell to get its color:

```js
// Hook click on the table
document.getElementById("my-table").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var element = event.target;
  while (element && element.tagName !== "TD") {
    if (element === this) {
      // No cell was clicked
      return;
    }
    element = element.parentNode;
  }

  // Show the color
  alert("Color: " + getComputedStyle(element).color);
}, false);
```

```css
.foo {
  color: red;
}
.bar {
  color: green;
}
.biz {
  color: blue;
}
.baz {
  color: #880;
}
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="foo">foo</td>
      <td class="bar">bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="biz">biz</td>
      <td class="baz">baz</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow that's it, that's exactly what I wanted it to do. I haven't come across getComputedStyle yet so no wonder I couldn't do it. I had been trying to use getElementbyID to get at the colour. Thanks very much indeed.